# Can I pass a dictionary key to a method and return the value?

Tags: python, dictionary

```
dogList = {
    "Shepard" : "Loki"
    "Lab" : "Odin"
    "Shitzu" : "Paul"}
```

Take the above python dictionary.  I want to set up a method where I pass the `KEY` and have the method return the `VALUE` associated with it.  However I want to make sure that the dictionary cannot be modified so I've been trying to use the `@property` tag.  This is essentially what I am trying to run:

```
@property
def DogList(self, breed = "Shitzu") #Setting up one a default
    return dogList[breed]
```

Now this is what I am running to test the method:

```
doggos = Dog() #class that contains the list
doggos.DogList("Shitzu")
```

When I run that I get the following error:

```
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Well, your method and your dictionary have the same name... that's gonna cause problems...

Comment: That's not how properties work. Just use a regular method.

Comment: @kindall sorry, that was a typo on my part.

Comment: Define a `CustomDict`  class that extends `dict`. Then, override the `__setattr__` method and throw an error every time it's invoked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several options:

- give to method copy of your dictionary (lookout for big dictionaries), e.g.:

  ```
  dog_list = {...}
  dog_list_copy = dict(dog_list)
  ```
- use a class, with private field, and expose only methods, e.g.:

  ```
  class Abc:

      ___dogs_list = {...}

      def get_name(self, breed = 'Shitzu'):
          return self.__dogs_list[breed]
  ```

Of course, there are methods to read and modify object protected with a double underscore, but that access will not be accidental.